# Recommmend a proper data structure

Tags: data-structures

I have an algorithm problem that needs binary tree structure similar to a binary tree.  but the difference is that it may have nodes apart from the original tree independently.

And each node has three types. The first type is to point out starting node and only one exists. The second type is to point out connecting node and of course, and the last type is to point out a leaf node.  Each edge has a cost to traverse to its bottom node.

Which data structure is good for me to cost to reach each node?

---

UPDATE

OK, I questioned this with data-structure tag so that I want to avoid to explain what the problem is. But inevitably, I explain about the problem  because of lack of my explaination and my poor English.

I have nodes lists and edges with costs. There is a starting node(root node), nodes where will be located in the middle of a tree and leaf nodes are the destination for my program to traverse starting from a root node. But some of the leaf nodes may be ignored depending on the value in it. It is not important anyway. I have to calculate all leaf nodes' cost to reach its node from the root node and get the maximum value for them. Now, The problem is to adjust the cost value in edges for all other leaf nodes to have the same total cost with the maximum cost. But the sum of the adjust values has to be the minumum.

Comment: why do u need the 3 types of nodes? it seems that they are all the same type. a node with no "children" is a leaf.

Comment: Why not just have one struct to encompass all nodes while keeping an instance variable to keep track of the start and a boolean field to keep track of whether a node is a leaf? You technically don't need this since as @OhadR has mentioned, a node with no children is a leaf. But if you really want to keep track of this, a bool member makes more sense than defining a new type of node.

Comment: @OhadR Yes. They don't have to have types but need to have the information to ignore the nodes that exist just for the connection and located in the position of the leaf node.

Comment: so we have class Node with the data, and 2 Nodes: left and right. if left and right are null/empty, we know that this is a leaf. o/w this is a "connection" node. and you have a "pointer" of type Node to the current Root. does this make sense?

Comment: You just described a binary tree, which by definition contains nodes that have those attributes. What makes you think that your application requires some special structure that's different from a standard binary tree?

Comment: @JimMischel Because, I need to have cost value to move to a bottom node . Can I assign the value to the bottom node's attribute? If then I think I can use the standard binary as you all said.

Comment: Which bottom node? A binary tree's root has multiple "bottom nodes." Even a node that's one level above the leaf level has two "bottom nodes." The information you've provided doesn't give enough information for us to picture the problem. Please explain the real problem you're trying to solve, rather than asking us if your custom tree structure will solve a problem that we don't know anything about.

Comment: @JimMischel I updated as your request. thanks for your advice.